# Is this an acceptable way to change state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to change one of the nested object's properties. I am not sure because I know that arrayCopy is a shallow copy so the objects inside the original array in the state aren't copied. However, when I change update element which should hold a reference to the original element, would that be the same as mutating the state?

```
let arrayCopy = [...state.array]; // [ {},{}...] copy some array of nested objects 
let updatedElement = arrayCopy[index]; // take some particular element 
updatedElement.flag = true; // change one of its properties 
return {...state, array: arrayCopy} // This is inside a reducer
```

Comment: does that help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Almost*, but you need to copy the object you're updating (setting `flag` on) like you have the other elements, you can't update it in place:

```
let arrayCopy = [...state.array]; // [ {},{}...] copy some array of nested objects 
let updatedElement = arrayCopy[index] = {...arrayCopy[index]}; // copy the element we're updating
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
updatedElement.flag = true; // change one of its properties 
return {...state, array: arrayCopy} // This is inside a reducer
```

Comment: Whilst correct in description I believe this is missing something like `arrayCopy[index] = updatedElement;` as the array copy won't contain the newly formed object.

Answer (score 4):

As deep copying whole is a heavy task, we can do something like this (deep copy only one element from array and handle it accordingly) -:

```
let updatedElement = {...state.array[index], flag: true};
return {...state, array: [...state.array, [index]: updatedElement]};
```

Comment: +1 although I personally wouldn't suggest using stringify (a deep clone) when dealing with redux/react state. Making sure the top level reference is changed is best here (unless of course details further down in the object also update).

Comment: the IDE tells me that ',' is expected instead if the ':' for [index]: updatedElement